# small generalization of a linear algebra exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

I came aross the following exercise and was wondering if the conditions are actually necessary or if we could generalize this. Here Hom$(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ is the Vectorspace of linear functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$

let $F$ be a function  Hom$(\mathbb R,\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ 
with $F$: $u \mapsto u(1)$ show that $F$ is linear.

The point is that I think this is valid also for $F$ defined on any function space. For instance
we know that $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(y)$ and $(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha \cdot f(x)$ from how functions are generally defined.

so $F(\alpha u)=(\alpha  u)(1)=\alpha \cdot u(1)=\alpha F(u)$

and $F(\alpha u+\beta v)=(\alpha u+ \beta v)(1)=(\alpha u)(1)+(\beta v)(1)=\alpha u(1)+\beta u(1)=\alpha F(u)+ \beta F(v)$ and hence we have linearity of $F$.

It appears a bit strange to me that the condition Hom$(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ is added so maybe I misunderstood the exercise or the definition of a Functionspace in general. Any clarification would be really great.

For me a funtion space is a Vectorspace wich has functions as vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works much more generally. If $V$ is a $K$-vector space ($K$ any field), and $X$ any set, for every $x\in X$, the evaluation map

$$\operatorname{ev}_x \colon \mathscr{F}(X,V) \to V;\quad \operatorname{ev}_x (f) = f(x)$$

is $K$-linear. That indeed follows directly from the definition of addition and scalar multiplication of functions as the pointwise operations.

($\mathscr{F}(A,B)$ denotes the set of all maps $A\to B$)

Comment: I showed that linearity of $F$ follows immediately from addition and scalar multiplication of functions as the pointwise operations (as you pointed out). So would my argument suffice to prove that $F$ is linear and hence to solve the specified exercise?

Comment: Yes. $F(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha F(u) + \beta F(v)$ is the linearity of $F$. Since you've shown that, you're done, linearity proven, exercise solved.

Comment: I often have difficulties on exams for solving exercises in a different way or bothering myself with unecesseray complications so it's very important for me to be really sure about an alternative approach. So I apologize for the possible triviality of the question and thank you very much.

Comment: No reason to apologize. You saw that the exercise was formulated more restrictedly than necessary. You weren't 100% sure that you didn't overlook something, so you asked for confirmation. Very sensible. With experience, the point where you stop being sure you didn't miss anything moves, but it'll always be somewhere.